# Gradle: consolidating multi project distributions into a single distribution

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I'm working on a gradle multi project (java), where some of the sub-projects are applications (have a main class, and are executable) and some others are libraries (e.g, ends up being packaged as a jar, which some other sub-projects define a dependency on). It's working fine.

I'd like to be able to package (tar) the entire project for production, according to some structure that will make it easy for my users to deploy and use later on.

Currently, the *distTar* task creates a `build/distribution/project-name.tar` for each application project, and a `build/libs/project-name.jar` for each non application project, under each project build directory. That's a step in the right direction, but I'd like to consolidate the contents into one thing I can distribute.

As an example, right now after running *distTar*:

```
myapp/
  README
  docs/
  services/
    service1/
      build/
        libs/service1.jar
        <other build dirs I don't want to distribute>
    service2/
      build/
        distributions/service2.tar
        <other build dirs I don't want to distribute>
    service3/
      build/
        distributions/service3.tar
        <other build dirs I don't want to distribute>
```

and the contents of service2.tar are:

```
service2/lib/service2.jar
service2/lib/some-service2-dependency.jar
service2/bin/service2 (start script)
service2/config.yml
```

(and similarly for service3.tar).

I'd like my final result to be a single myapp.tar(.gz) that includes a similar directory structure, but only with the production files:

```
README
docs/
services/
  service1/
    lib/service1.jar
  service2/
    lib/service2.jar
    lib/some-service-dependency.jar
    bin/service2 (start script)
    config.yml
  service3/
    lib/service3.jar
    lib/some-service-dependency.jar
    bin/service3 (start script)
    config.yml
```

Not sure what is the best way to achieve such a task. Do I create a parent level task that depends on distTar and copies files around, untar'ing stuff, etc? (tried that unsuccessfully).

Many thanks!

UPDATE:
I started doing something along these lines:

```
distributions {
    main {
        contents {
            into('scripts') {
                from {'scripts/sbin'}
            }
            into('service1') {
                from {tarTree(tarFileForProject("service1"))}
            }
            into('service2') {
                from {tarTree(tarFileForProject("service2"))}
            }
            into ...
        }
    }
}
distTar.dependsOn([subprojects.clean, subprojects.distTar])
```

(where tarFileForProject is a simple function that returns the path to the build/distributions/*.tar file of the given subproject name).

It seems to work, but also seems ugly. I wonder if there's a cleaner way to do this.

Comment: The distribution plugin appears to support some mild configuration, but it sounds like you might be better off writing your own task. http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/distribution_plugin.html

Comment: Thanks @SirBraneDamuj. The 'writing it my own' part is what I'm struggling with and asking for advice :)